# 2019 Server GPO Not Applying to Windows 10 Systems

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2019

I am having an issue with a freshly built 2019 Active Directory Domain. I built this domain from the ground up in parallel to the existing and very broken 2008 r2 domain and so far everything has been beautiful, except Global Policies do not apply to anything - not to the computers, root, or to the OUs within.

The Order of Operation is correct. I have the Default Domain Policy running at the root of the Company folder and set to enforced. I then have 4 OU's within that folder for Desktops, Servers, Workboards and Exempt.  Desktops fully inherits anything from root and the gpo's linked to the desktop ou, Servers and Exempt are more restrictive and workboards do not get any gpo's.

I have followed many fix procedures but nothing works. The one solution to at least one GPO makes no sense (the reason GPO cannot be applied is RPC and WMI are blocked in the firewall preventing remote policy changes). Microsoft's solution is to create a GPO to enable these in the Firewall, however since RPC and WMI are still blocking remote policy changes this is a catch 22 so the only solution would be to manually go to each desktop fix the firewall or disable it all together to get the firewall gpo to run to get the remaining gpo's to run.

I digress.  I am starting to believe this is a known issue that Microsoft is aware of but has refused to admit.  Anyone else having these issues? and if so any luck resolving it??

Comment: You should check event log on the client computers, and see what `gpresult /r report.html` says.